# How to place html2canvas image into other html page

Tags: javascript, highcharts

i want to ask here.
i have create a code for convert a highchart line chart into a canvas with html2canvas. im success make that code but i want to make the image that i grab passing into my other html page. i want to place it into a div called `#main-container' on`report.html`. i don't know how to pass the image that i grab into it.

please someone help me to do that. 
this is my code for grab my highchart

```js
('#export').bind('click', function() {
  html2canvas($("#grafik"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var imgsrc = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      $('<img src="' + imgsrc + '" />').appendTo('#main-container');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you know if visitor opens "report.html"?

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem in Highcharts. Are Highcharts causing any issues for you in this case?